# How to integrate app Invites for Android with Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook

I'm quite new to Android and I don't quite understand importing classes so please point me in the right direction. I've added the Facebook SDK to my project via Gradle.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

In my Java class, I have the following imports:

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.*;
```

When I add the following code from [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android) link:

```
String appLinkUrl, previewImageUrl;

appLinkUrl = "https://www.example.com/myapplink";
previewImageUrl = "https://www.example.com/my_invite_image.jpg";

if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
    AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
        .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
        .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
        .build();
    AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
}
```

The app throws the following errors:

```
Error: cannot find symbol variable AppInviteDialog
Error: cannot find symbol variable AppInviteContent
```

What do I need to import/modify for this to work correctly?

Comment: Make sure you have API 24 installed and you are compiling with API 24???

Comment: Just by a quick look this doesn't look right to me: `[4,5)` Probably there is something messed up with the brackets. EDIT: nevermind, looks like this is an actual syntax o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need following imports....in general IDEs like Android Studio will give you option to add these imports

```
import com.facebook.share.model.AppInviteContent;
import com.facebook.share.widget.AppInviteDialog;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I am in Android Studio but for some reason it doesn't show me these, only the import Facebook ones

Answer (score 0):

If you have already the 2 imports and it won't work, try adding this in your `build.gradle` of your app:

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.23.0'
```